# dplyr inconsistent behaviour inside function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, variable-assignment

This problem happens when instead of using the dplyr::mutate function on its own, I insert it in a function, it doesnt work! Look:

```
library(tidyverse)
data1<-data.frame(a=c(1:2), x1=c(2:3))

fun <- function(df1, coldf1){
  df1 %>% mutate(coldf1 = 1) %>% return()
}

fun(data1, "a")
data1 %>% mutate("a" = 1)
```

The two codes are identical but the results are unexpected like so:

```
> fun(data1, "a")
  a x1 coldf1
1 1  2      1
2 2  3      1
> data1 %>% mutate("a" = 1)
  a x1
1 1  2
```

I know something is up with the assignment with the equality, and the same problem happened in the left_join function too. Is there a universal solution for these things?

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: You can't do `coldf1` like that using dplyr, look into non-standard evaluation (NSE) in `dplyr`, `rlang`, and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `dplyr`, which is heavily into "non-standard evaluation" (NSE). Inside your function, `dplyr` sees `coldf1 = 1` and assigns a new column, just like you can do `df1 %>% mutate(somethingnew = 3.1415)`.

You need to use either `rlang`'s escaping mechanisms (with `:=`) ...

```r
fun <- function(df1, coldf1) {
  df1 %>% mutate(!!coldf1 := 1)
}

data1
#   a x1
# 1 1  2
# 2 2  3
fun(data1, "a")
#   a x1
# 1 1  2
# 2 1  3
```

or basic R :

```r
fun <- function(df1, coldf1) { df1[[coldf1]] <- 1; df1; }
fun(data1, "a")
#   a x1
# 1 1  2
# 2 1  3
```

(though I'm assuming your example is simplified, where this might not be as simple)

Regardless, look into "programming with dplyr", https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.